# Error: el objeto no tiene un atributo

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que la salida en consola me muestra un error que dice:

> AttributeError: type object 'Persona' has no attribute 'saludar'
>   ()

¿Por qué ocurre eso y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: por favor, añade en la pregunta el código relevante. Las imágenes (y más aún enlaces externos) complican las cosas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un problema de identación. Los métodos de una clase deben ir "dentro" de ella. Prueba identando:

```
class Persona:
    nombre = " "
    edad = 0
    pais = " "
    def saludar(self):
        print("Hola mi mombre es", self.nombre)
    def otroMetodo(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Funcionó, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Python usa mucho la identación y debes cuidarla, para que la clase Persona tenga el método saludar, debes colocar tu código de la siguiente forma

```
class Persona:
    nombre = " "
    edad = 0
    pais = " "

    def saludar(self):
        print("Hola mi nombre es", self.nombre)
```

igualmente con el otro método

Comment: Funcionó, gracias!

Comment: Si te funcionó puedes puntuar mi respuesta